# Delete a variable in pulp

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I have a optimize problem: there are 3 binary variable x, y, z.
The objective func is: x + y + z max
The constraint is: 2x + 3y - 4z <= 5
I want to fix a random variable = 1 (or 0). In this problem i fix x = 1. Now I don't know how to change the constraint base on that variable automatically, it like x is not variable anymore or it will be deleted, the solver just solve y and z.
The reason why i need to do it automatically is in my real problem it can be have 100+ variable.
Please help me, Thank you!
(I am using pulp, if you know library can do it, please recommend for me)

i try to convert the constraint to string, change them base on the fixed variable then convert again, but it seem not true.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `pulp`'s commands to fix variables?  You should be able to fix any variable and then solve.  Key syntax:

```
In [9]: import pulp as plp

In [10]: x = plp.LpVariable('x')

In [11]: x.setInitialValue(5)
Out[11]: True

In [12]: x.fixValue()

In [13]: x.isFixed()
Out[13]: True

In [14]: x.isFree()
Out[14]: False
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot, but now i want to delete that variable. Does the constraint become this: 2*1 + 3y - 4z <= 5 or this:  3y - 4z <= 5 ?